# How do I know which browser is used to crawl in Scrapy framework?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

What's my context:

- As you know, website HTML structure on Chrome, Firefox, Safari are quite different. So when I'm using CSS-Selector to get data in an element tag from HTML structure, sometimes It that tag is already have with Chrome browser but the other is not. So that, I just want to focus on only one browser to reduce my effort.
- When I crawl data from urls by using Scrapy framework, I don't know which browser will be used by Scrapy to crawl data. Therefore, I also don't know what kind of HTML response body be returned. I checked the response and I found that sometimes the structure is the same as getting from Chrome but sometimes It's not. It seems that Scrapy framework used many different web browsers to crawl data.

What I want:

- I want to use only Chrome browser for crawling data in Scrapy framework
- The structure of the HTML response body must be obtained from Chrome

What I ask:

- Does anyone have any Ideas or tips to help me deal with that issue?
- Can I config the Webdriver in Scrapy Framework as Selenium does? (If It's possible, please show me Where and How?)

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scrapy` does not use Browser, it parser for static html like `BeautifulSoup`. if you want to parse dynamic page (javascript generated) use `selenium` and if you want you can send the page source to Scrapy.

To set Scrapy to use custom user agent (Chrome), in `settings.py` add

```
USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36
```

or in `my_spider.py`

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls, callback=self.parse, headers={"User-Agent": "Your Custom User Agent"})
```

Comment: Good answer +1. Just one more thing, That we need to add multiple User_Agent to cover the case that the server (which we are crawling) will restrict our User_Agent when we use that User_Agent too many times.

Comment: just create random user agent or add delay to the request, doing it too fast sometimes will block the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user agent in your setting file, something like this

```
USER_AGENT = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'
```

So for web server it will look like the request is generating from Chrome.

Comment: I tried, But It doesn't help. :'( 
Here the url I want to crawl:  https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g297701-d8293999-Reviews-Mandapa_a_Ritz_Carlton_Reserve-Ubud_Gianyar_Bali.html
Here my USER_AGENT: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'

Comment: Please post your complete code.  Also, how do you know that it does not work when the tripadivisor is the sever you are hitting ?

Comment: I know by using CSS-Selector to get data from element tag in HTML response which has in chrome but doesn't have in the others.
But Thanks for your answer, I think I found out the root cause. I need to set multiple User_Agent, because at the first time I crawled, it was Chrome HTML response but I tried so many time with that User_Agent, then the server restricted my User_Agent. That's why I got another response not from Chrome.

Comment: Interesting, although I find it weird that a application will restrict a particular user-agent request. If somebody decides to dissuades scrappers they generally block request if the figure it is from scrapper. Also generally the browser difference does not change html structures. So, generally if you are scrapping data the xpath based on html structures more than works out. Anyway, best of luck with your scrapping.